# C++ 2D How to "stick" an exhaust sprite on a spaceship and allowing it to rotate accordingly?

Tags: c++, 2d

What exactly is the formula to needed to do this?

So if I have two separate sprites named player (a spaceship) and exhaust (an exhaust animation for the bottom of the spaceship)

What math is needed so that when player rotates, the exhaust moves and positions itself at the bottom of the ship which could be to the left at this point, if player has rotated 90 degrees right.

I know how to spin / rotate the sprites to face the right direction. What I need to know is how to move the exhaust so that it's positioned correctly at the bottom of the ship when the ship turns.

And please don't link any "Move a sprite around a point" threads and such since that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I actually did this exact thing in a Coursera Python course. I forgot the math but I believe it used some simple trig.  This is the course. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=px0KrpSa9f4.  You will likely not find the videos on Coursera, but Youtube or another website is a possibility.  Week 7 I believe is what you want.  It covers, in fact, all of the physics you'd need for an Asteroids type game.

Comment: Ideally you would just offset the local position and apply a rotation transformation; but I can't be certain that's what you need, because you haven't specified which APIs you're using, nor have you posted any of your coding attempts.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the ship is similar to the one in the game "[Asteroids](http://www.freeasteroids.org/)", the position of the tail of the ship (relative to the ship's center) will be described by a circle whose radius is the distance between the center of the ship and the ship's tail.

Given that, you can calculate the position of the tail of the ship like this:

```
#include <math.h>

[...]

double radius = ship_height/2.0;
double ship_heading = /* current angle of rotation of the ship, in radians, e.g. 0 if the ship is facing right, pi if it is facing left, etc */
double tail_heading = ship_heading + 3.14159;  /* ship's tail faces the opposite direction from the nose! */
double x_offset = cos(tail_heading)*radius;
double y_offset = sin(tail_heading)*radius;
double exhaust_center_x = ship_center_x + x_offset;
double exhaust_center_y = ship_center_y + y_offset;
```

(and if you want the exhaust-graphic to appear a little farther away from the tail of the ship, just increase the radius value slightly)